# How to consolidate these many rake tasks into one task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

The application I'm working on runs import tasks each night to get information from an external database and processes and writes it to the local PostgreSQL database. This is so it can be viewed in our application.

We do the following:

- Create a connection to the external database
- Perform some currency conversion
- Do some calculations on the data based on the average
- Check if the item already exists and update if it's changed
- Also check to see how it is classified and change the category to fit our categorisations
- Create the item if it does not exist

All of this data is on different tables in the external database, so I've created a task for each table (about 30), but I am repeating myself excessively so looking for some guidance on how to DRY this bad boy up.

Is it possible to create some kind of loop on a collection of the external database table names? I've tried this a couple of times but haven't had any success. Please find the code below of examples of two different import scripts.

```
desc 'Imports ABC Data'
task :abcdeal_import => :environment do

    # Connect to legacy db

    class OldDb < ActiveRecord::Base
        establish_connection :cleardb
        self.table_name = 'abcdeal'
    end

    class Import < OldDb
        self.table_name = 'abcdeal'
    end

    # Currency Conversion

    require 'money'
    require 'money/bank/google_currency'

    # set the seconds after than the current rates are automatically expired
    Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.ttl_in_seconds = 86400
    # set default bank to instance of GoogleCurrency
    bank = Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.new

        @gbp = bank.get_rate(:USD, :GBP).to_f
        @eur = bank.get_rate(:USD, :EUR).to_f
        @aud = bank.get_rate(:USD, :AUD).to_f      
        @cad = bank.get_rate(:USD, :CAD).to_f    
        @nzd = bank.get_rate(:USD, :NZD).to_f      

    Import.all.find_each do |u|

        # Define Variables

        @price = u.UnitPrice
        @interest = u.UnitSold
        #@interest_changes = u.unitsold_changes
        @company = u.Company
        @legacy_id = u.id
        @end_date = u.EndDate
        @category = u.Category
        @revenue = u.Revenue

        # Calculate average

        @company_average = company_average(@company)        

        if @company_average == 0
            @company_average = 1
        end

        # Does item exist?
        if Dailydeal.exists?(:legacy_id => @legacy_id, :company => @company)
        # It exists.
            @historical_interest = Product.where(:legacy_id => @legacy_id).pluck(:interest)                
            # Another statement to check that the Interest != UnitSold
            if @interest != @historical_interest
            Product.where(:legacy_id => @legacy_id, :company => @company).update_all(:interest => @interest, :end_date => @end_date, :interest_changes => @interest_changes, :status => average_change_interest, :revenue => @revenue, :revenue_eur => eur_revenue_currency_conversion, :revenue_aud => aud_revenue_currency_conversion, :revenue_gbp => gbp_revenue_currency_conversion, :revenue_cad => cad_revenue_currency_conversion, :revenue_nzd => nzd_revenue_currency_conversion)
            end
        else
        # Doesn't exist

        # Set Category            

        case @category
            when 'Apparel'
                @category = 'Apparel & Footwear'

            when 'Gadgets'
                @category = 'Electronics & Accessories'

            when 'Gifts'
                @category = 'Miscellaneous'

            when 'Health & Cosmetics'
                @category = 'Health & Beauty'

            when 'Home'
                @category = 'Home & Furniture'

            when 'Other'
                @category = 'Miscellaneous'

            when 'Toys'
                @category = 'Toys & Kids'

            else

                @category

            end

        Product.create(
              :name => u.ProductName,
              :link => u.ProductLink,
              :image_url => u.ImageUrl,
              :price => u.UnitPrice,
              :interest => u.UnitSold,
              :start_date => u.StartDate,
              :end_date => u.EndDate,
              :revenue => u.Revenue,
              :company => u.Company,
              :category => @category,
              :country => u.Country,
              :price_eur => eur_currency_conversion,
              :price_aud => aud_currency_conversion,
              :price_gbp => gbp_currency_conversion,
              :price_cad => cad_currency_conversion,
              :price_nzd => nzd_currency_conversion,
              :revenue_eur => eur_revenue_currency_conversion,
              :revenue_aud => aud_revenue_currency_conversion,
              :revenue_gbp => gbp_revenue_currency_conversion,
              :revenue_cad => cad_revenue_currency_conversion,
              :revenue_nzd => nzd_revenue_currency_conversion,
              :status => average_change_interest,
              :legacy_id => u.id)
        end
    end

    puts "Successfully imported data from abc"

end

desc 'Imports def Data'
task :def_import => :environment do

    # Connect to legacy db

    class OldDb < ActiveRecord::Base
        establish_connection :cleardb
        self.table_name = 'def'
    end

    class Import < OldDb
        self.table_name = 'def'
    end

    # Currency Conversion

    require 'money'
    require 'money/bank/google_currency'

    # set the seconds after than the current rates are automatically expired
    Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.ttl_in_seconds = 86400
    # set default bank to instance of GoogleCurrency
    bank = Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.new

        @gbp = bank.get_rate(:USD, :GBP).to_f
        @eur = bank.get_rate(:USD, :EUR).to_f
        @aud = bank.get_rate(:USD, :AUD).to_f      
        @cad = bank.get_rate(:USD, :CAD).to_f    
        @nzd = bank.get_rate(:USD, :NZD).to_f      

    Import.all.find_each do |u|

        # Define Variables

        @price = u.UnitPrice
        @interest = u.UnitSold
        #@interest_changes = u.unitsold_changes
        @company = u.Company
        @legacy_id = u.id
        @end_date = u.EndDate
        @category = u.Category
        @revenue = u.Revenue

        # Calculate average

        @company_average = company_average(@company)

        if @company_average == 0
            @company_average = 1
        end

        # Does item exist?
        if Product.exists?(:legacy_id => @legacy_id, :company => @company)
        # It exists.
            @historical_interest = Product.where(:legacy_id => @legacy_id).pluck(:interest)                
            # Another statement to check that the Interest != UnitSold
            if @interest != @historical_interest
                Product.where(:legacy_id => @legacy_id, :company => @company).update_all(:interest => @interest, :end_date => @end_date, :interest_changes => @interest_changes, :status => average_change_interest, :revenue => @revenue, :revenue_eur => eur_revenue_currency_conversion, :revenue_aud => aud_revenue_currency_conversion, :revenue_gbp => gbp_revenue_currency_conversion, :revenue_cad => cad_revenue_currency_conversion, :revenue_nzd => nzd_revenue_currency_conversion)
            end
        else
        # Doesn't exist

        # Set Categories    

        case @category

            when 'Adult Products'
                @category

            when 'Arts & Crafts', 'Furniture', 'Garden', 'Large Appliances', 'Lighting', 'Outdoor & Patio', 'Stationary', 'Storage & Organization'
                @category = 'Home & Furniture'

            when 'Audio & Audio Accessories', 'Electronics Accessories', 'Gadgets', 'GPS & Car Accessories', 'Tools & Hardware', 'Tablets'
                @category = 'Electronics & Accessories'

            when 'Automotive Services'
                @category = 'Automotive'

            when 'Bath', 'Bedding'
                @category = 'Bed & Bath'

            when 'Books & Media', 'Canada', 'Gifts', 'Miscellaneous', 'Recreational'
                @category = 'Miscellaneous'

            when 'Cafe, Bakery & Treats', 'Kitchen'
                @category = 'Kitchen'

            when 'Casual Restaurants', 'Cleaning Services', 'Dance Classes', 'Fast Food', 'Fine Dining', 'Home Services', 'Local Exhibits & Shows', 'Other Services', 'Other Workshops & Classes', 'Outdoor Adventures', 'Other Activities', 'Tours & Sightseeing', 'Fitness Classes', 'Massage', 'Med Spa', 'Salon & Hair Care Services', 'Spa Services', 'Yoga, Pilates & Aerobics'
                @category = 'Experiences'

            when 'Cats', 'Dogs', 'Pets', 'Pets Accessories'
                @category = 'Pets Accessories'

            when 'Clothing', 'Clothing, Fashion & Accessories', 'Fashion & Accessories', 'Footwear', "Men's", 'Unisex', "Women's"
                @category = 'Apparel & Footwear'

            when 'Earrings', 'Fashion Accessories'
                @category = 'Jewellery & Accessories'

            when 'Fitness', 'Hair Care', 'Hair Removal', 'Health Care', 'Manicure & Pedicure', 'Other Beauty & Spa', 'Other Health & Fitness', 'Personal Care', 'Teeth Whitening', 'Wellness & Nutrition', 'Facial'
            @category = 'Health & Beauty'

            when 'Golf', 'Sports', 'Football', 'Baseball', 'Hockey', 'Ice Hockey'
                @category = 'Sporting Accessories'

        else

            @category

        end            

        Product.create(
              :name => u.ProductName,
              :link => u.ProductLink,
              :image_url => u.ImageUrl,
              :price => u.UnitPrice,
              :interest => u.UnitSold,
              :start_date => u.StartDate,
              :end_date => u.EndDate,
              :revenue => u.Revenue,
              :company => u.Company,
              :category => @category,
              :country => u.Country,
              :price_eur => eur_currency_conversion,
              :price_aud => aud_currency_conversion,
              :price_gbp => gbp_currency_conversion,
              :price_cad => cad_currency_conversion,
              :price_nzd => nzd_currency_conversion,
              :revenue_eur => eur_revenue_currency_conversion,
              :revenue_aud => aud_revenue_currency_conversion,
              :revenue_gbp => gbp_revenue_currency_conversion,
              :revenue_cad => cad_revenue_currency_conversion,
              :revenue_nzd => nzd_revenue_currency_conversion,
              :status => average_change_interest,
              :legacy_id => u.id)
        end
    end

    puts "Successfully imported data from def"

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This indeed look repetitive, why can't you come up with a Structure like this and not put everything in below format

```
.
├── Rakefile
└── models
    ├── import.rb
    └── old_db.rb
```

I did similar kind of thing, for one of my project where i am extracting data from a DB, you can also refer to it here https://github.com/ankit8898/sql-server-mapper

Comment: Hey thanks very much for your reply. I am using the Heroku Scheduler to run the import tasks, so they are all in a file called scheduler.rake .. so you think I should actually specifically create the models? And then call them from the rake task?

Comment: @bnussey, yeah i prefer keeping it in separate spaces.  So you can create your models and require them in the .rake.  You can check the repo in the above url

Comment: Got ya.. I was kind of looking for some sort of way to DRY up the whole task, like all the stuff it is doing, any ideas? Maybe write the script once and then somehow loop through the different models